# Emeditor pro Find in files to find multiple files

Tags: emeditor, findinfiles

I am looking for a way to search many files of one file type for a large number of strings.

Example:
Search Doc1.txt, Doc2.txt, Doc3.txt

on Drive C:

Search For aaa.rtf, aba.rtf, ccc.rtf

The standard find in files looks for one single string in many files but not multiple.
Edit: This appears to be possible by using batch find.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: After contacting support it appears that this is possible using the Batch function. After attempting to do so, it appears that the files I'm searching aren't clear enough to yield viable results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To search multiple files for multiple strings, you can use the **Batch Find in Files** feature of EmEditor. To do this:

1. Select the list of search strings, separated by newlines:

```
aaa.rtf
aba.rtf
ccc.rtf
```

in EmEditor or Notepad, and copy the list to the Clipboard. This will make it easier to set up the list in **Batch Find in Files** later.

2. In EmEditor, select **Find in Files** on the **Search** menu (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>).

[image: EmEditor - Find in Files]

3. Click the **Batch >>** button in the **Find in Files** dialog box if the **Find in Files** dialog box appears instead of the **Batch Find in Files** dialog box.

[image: EmEditor - Batch Find in Files]

4. Right-click the list on the right side of the **Batch Find in Files** dialog box, and select **Paste** (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>). This will paste the list of search strings you copied in the Step 1.
5. Make sure **File Types** (`*.txt`) and **In Folder** (`C:\`) are correct.
6. Click the **Batch Find** button to find all strings in the specified file types of the specified folder.

If you would like to record these steps as a macro, select **Start/Stop Record** on the **Macros** menu (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, or click the **Start Recording** button on the toolbar) before you do the above step 2. After you do the above step 6, select **Start/Stop Record** on the **Macros** menu (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, or click the **Start Recording** button on the toolbar) again. Once you recorded a macro, you can save it as a macro file by selecting **Save As...** on the **Macros** menu. You will get a macro file similar to this:

```
batch_list = editor.filters;
batch_list.AddFind("aaa.rtf",eeFindReplaceEscSeq,0);
batch_list.AddFind("aba.rtf",eeFindReplaceEscSeq,0);
batch_list.AddFind("ccc.rtf",eeFindReplaceEscSeq,0);
editor.BatchFindInFiles(batch_list,"C:\\*.txt",0,0,"",0,0);
```

Later, you can select **Select...** on the **Macros** menu to select this macro, and then select **Run** on the **Macros** menu to run this macro.